# Say caller name feature

Tags: calls, text-to-speech, caller-id

I am missing that feature from Nokia devices, Is there a chance to make my Xperia X10 say callers name when I have incoming call

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The application [SayMyName Dessert](http://www.appbrain.com/app/saymyname-dessert/org.mailboxer.saymyname) does this quite well.